# Microsoft Graph filter on a displayName with + in it

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

We have automation code that has been running for quire some time now.

The code retrieves a specified Azure AD Group by displayName. In some cases, the displayName contains a + sign. Until recently, that was not an issue, but now the query returns nothing, it we query the displayName with a + in it.

The uri looks like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=startswith(displayName,'My Group with a + in it')
```

If we only query the part up to the + sign, the group is returned as expected.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=startswith(displayName,'My Group with a')
```

This has been working, but we would be more then happy with a solution that enables us to just escape the + sign and get the payload. We have tried url-encoding the uri without any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue, to fix it, just url-encode the `+` sign with `%2B`, refer to the sample below.

In my sample, my group named `joytest+group`, I filter it with `joytest+g`, encode the `+` sign, then it will be `joytest%2Bg`.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=startswith(displayName,'joytest%2Bg')
```

Test in the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), it works fine.

[image]